# babel generated code breaking istanbul coverage

Tags: javascript, babeljs, istanbul

I'm using `babel` to enable ES6 imports in a node project. Also using `mocha` for testing, and `istanbul` for coverage. I end up with less than full coverage because babel generates code something like the following:

```
'use strict';

 Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", {
     value: true
 });

 var _promise = require('babel-runtime/core-js/promise');

 var _promise2 = _interopRequireDefault(_promise);

 var _koa = require('koa');

 var _koa2 = _interopRequireDefault(_koa);

 function _interopRequireDefault(obj) { return obj && obj.__esModule ? obj : { default: obj }; }
```

Specifically, the generated function `_interopRequireDefault` is copied into every code file, and the branches are not necessarily always executed, which skews the branch coverage number emitted for `istanbul`. Is there any way around this issue?

Comment: What are you using as your test runner? (if any)

Comment: Using gulp and mocha, quite similar to the setup shown by @ssube below

Answer (score 2):

If you're using gulp, I have a gist with a [gulpfile here](https://gist.github.com/ssube/f9973096511d9f4b20ea568e7f7e337c#file-gulpfile-babel-js-L31) that sets up the necessary hooks and filters. The relevant chunk is to load [isparta](https://www.npmjs.com/package/isparta), hook require, and let the tests run:

```
gulp.task('test:cover', (cb) => {
  gulp.src('src/main/**/*.js')
    .pipe(istanbul({
      instrumenter: require('isparta').Instrumenter,
      includeUntested: true
    }))
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('target/cover'))
    .pipe(istanbul.hookRequire())
    .on('finish', cb);
});

gulp.task('test:mocha', (cb) => {
  gulp.src('target/test/**/Test*')
    .pipe(mocha())
    .pipe(istanbul.writeReports())
    .on('end', cb);
});

gulp.task('test', (cb) => {
  return runSequence('test:cover', 'test:mocha', cb);
});
```

The only frustrating part is that your tests [must use the covered code](https://gist.github.com/ssube/f9973096511d9f4b20ea568e7f7e337c#file-example-tests-js-L2):

```
import {
  LinearInterpolator,
  CosineInterpolator
} from '../../cover/random/Interpolators';
```

I haven't found a way to work around that yet without also covering the test scripts and skewing coverage, although you should be able to do that by merging streams:

```
gulp.task('test:cover', (cb) => {
  const src = gulp.src('src/main/**/*.js')
    .pipe(istanbul({
      instrumenter: require('isparta').Instrumenter,
      includeUntested: true
    }));

  const test = gulp.src('src/test/**/*.js');

  merge(src, test)
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('target/cover'))
    .pipe(istanbul.hookRequire())
    .on('finish', cb);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine it with isparta - https://github.com/douglasduteil/isparta - to get the coverage working correctly. I warn you its a bit trial and error at the moment! My npm script looks like -

```
"coverage": "node_modules/.bin/babel-node node_modules/.bin/isparta cover --include-all-sources --report html node_modules/.bin/_mocha -- --reporter $npm_package_config_bdd_reporter",
```

Comment: is `isparta` a completely different coverage tool (instead of `istanbul`)? I might consider it, but generally everything works right now because node 6.2 supports virtually everything in es6 except the imports/exports. So my use of babel is minimal and that single generated function is my only actual problem. It looks like `istanbul` has a way to ignore certain lines but only with code comments (e.g. `/* istanbul ignore next */`), but that doesn't quite cut it since I don't control the code being generated.

Comment: @Kevin my understanding is that it uses istanbul under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

We've run into this and I finally got fed up and looked into what causes this line. It turns out that every time to use an `import` like:

```
import chai from 'chai';
```

this babel fill gets added to allow sane interaction with older export styles. The trouble is that none of the common libraries exhibit the "true" branch of the ternary. I build the following file `coverInterrop.js` that artificially trips the first branch using old-school exports:

```
module.exports = {
    __esModule: true
};
```

and I include in any file where I want to use an undestructured import:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
import coverInterrop from 'coverInterrop';
```

Note that it has to assign to a variable to trip the coverage and good eslint rules won't like that